# digital clock in Java

Tags: java, swing

any builtin classes available to display the digital clock in Java?

Comment: You mean a 7-segmented display of the numbers?

Answer (score 2):

i dont think there are any built in, but they are pretty easy to develop.  there is a [swing timer utility](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) that you can use.  here is a [demo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Timerclocklabel.htm)

Answer (score 0):

No, not that I'm aware of.

However, assuming the use of Swing, one could use the [`JLabel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) class or the like use its [`setText`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)) method to show display the current time. (Another option is to extend the `JLabel` to display the current time as well.)

If one needs to actually make a subclass of [`JComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) which displays a seven-segment digit-like display by writing a custom `paintComponent` method to draw the digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the date and time with

```
System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
```